# Is it an acceptable way to use class' private methods in C++?

Tags: c++

In my C++ program I have a class, in some methods of which there are same routines happen, such as opening streams for reading/writing to files, parsing files, determining mime types, etc. Same routines are also used in constructor. To make methods more compact and avoid typing same code multiple times I split these routine operations into private methods for using inside the class only. However, some of these private methods depend on the result of the others, so that calling these methods in wrong order could lead in pretty bad consequences.
Just a stupid example:

```
class Example
{
    public:
        Example(int x);
        ~Example() {}
        //...
        //...
    protected:

    private:
        int a;
        int b;
        bool c;
        void foo_();
        void bar_();
        //...
        //...
};

Example::Example(int x) : a(x)
{
    foo_();
    bar_();
}

void Example::foo_()
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
        b = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        b = a * 2;
    }
}

void Example::bar_()
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        c = false;
    }
    else
    {
        c = true;
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the above example, calling `bar_()` before `foo_()` in constructor will lead in undefined behavior because `b` has not been yet initialized. But should I bother about such nuances if I am definitely sure that I am using these private methods correctly inside the class, and they can never be used outside the class?

Comment: Yes, it is, why not...

Comment: Just because you didn't explicitly initialize it doesn't mean you don't get a default. To be clear you should initialize it in any constructor lists, though.

Comment: The most important thing is to add documentation, at least as comments, or perhaps in some other file (you could use [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) to write the documentation), about your C++ code. Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use it as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` ...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). And you could write the documentation of your code with a pencil and paper. Read also books about [programming in C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Comment: @tadman, yes, but the default might not be the expected value.

Comment: What would you expect other than the default if you didn't initialize it?

Comment: I don't see the UB. You don't read `b` when it's uninitialized that I can see.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I just used the wrong term and the example is too stupid. I have modified it a little bit.  By 'undefined' I meant the behavior differ from what is expected, i.e. `bar_()` should use the value of `b` assigned in `foo_()`, but instead it uses the default value that breaks the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to mention that what you did *is* the recommended way! Whenever you have multiple different operations inside a function, the standard way is to separate the function into multiple functions. In your case, the user does not need those functions, so making them private was the best you could do! When it comes to the part where "I need to call them in a specific order", its entirely fine if the code needs calls in a particular order. I mean, its only logical to call `foo` after `bar` is the former depends on the result of the later. It's not much different than when you need to assign memory to `int* p` before using it as an array. Although, as @Basil and many others have explained, be sure to document your code correctly

Answer (score 2):

> calling bar_() before foo_() in constructor will lead in undefined behavior because b has not been yet initialized

As a rule of thumb, I always *explicitly* initialize *all* member fields in a constructor (in particular those having a scalar type like pointers or numbers, e.g. your `a`,`b`,`c` inside `class Example`). Advantage: the behavior of your program is more reproducible. Disadvantage: the compiled code might run useless initialization (but clever optimizing compilers would remove them).

If you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), use it as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. It usually gives you useful warnings.

**For a large C++ project, consider documenting your coding rules** (in a separate written document, on paper, distributed to all developers in your team) and checking *some* of them with your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). See also the [DECODER](http://decoder-project.eu/) project and the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer, and the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (all of GCC, Bismon and Clang analyzer are open source, you can improve their source code).

**In some cases some C++ code is generated**. See [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/) as examples of software projects generating C++ code or providing code generators emitting C++ code. On x86/64 PCs, you could generate *machine code* at runtime with [ASMJIT](https://asmjit.com/) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), and call that code thru function pointers (on Linux see also [dlopen(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [dlsym(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) and the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html)...). If your software project has C++ code generators (e.g. using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)), you can ensure that the generated code respects *some* of your coding conventions and invariants. Be however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

If you debug with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), read about its [`watch` command and watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

I am also aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).